# Check, if in .map (), that object exists in another array React

Tags: reactjs, if-statement

How can I see in the map of products if that product is in the favorites?

```
Log of products 

[
{id: 1, product_name: “product one”},
{id: 2, product_name: “product two”},
{id: 3, product_name: “product three”}
]

Log of favorites

[
{id: 1, product_name: “product one”},
{id: 2, product_name: “product two”}
]

{products.map((item} => 
// Here, if the product is in the favorites list then show x else show y
// I need to check here if the product is in the favorites list, to show two different types of icons
)
```

I don’t know how to do, I also tried to map to favorites with product id = favorite product id, but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var products = [{
    id: 1,
    product_name: 'product one'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    product_name: 'product two'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    product_name: 'product three'
  }
]
var favorites = [{
    id: 1,
    product_name: 'product one'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    product_name: 'product two'
  }
]

const solution = products.map((product)=>{
  return favorites.find(el=>el.product_name === product.product_name) ? 'x' : 'y'
})
```

Comment: `.find` technically returns the object from the list, not a boolean "exists". `.some` is strictly "does it exist". There are some strange edge cases where `.find` and `.some` could give a different result.